# Validate http headers for authentication in every page using nuxt.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to validate **every HTTP request** to the nuxt server for authorization.

In this [official tutorial](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-validate/),
it requires me to add a validate function in **every page**, which seems not to work for me, as **I'm seeking a way to write a middleware that validates all requests to the nuxt server**.

And so, I found nuxt's middleware support, but the official document is really unfriendly, I can't understand at all.

What I'm expecting is a **plugin-like** module that allows me to put my middleware into nuxt.
Just like what can be achievable in Express (as following).

```js
export default function (req, res, next)
```

So that I can easily validate headers per request to nuxt.

How can I achieve this? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure what you means by **every HTTP request to the nuxt server for authorization.** ? Are referring to HTTP request to [Nuxt servermiddleware](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware)?

Comment: @zernonia Thanks for your question. For example, for any url requests, I want to intercept the http request before nuxt starts rendering the page, so that I can validates whether the request has permission to view the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Nuxt Middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#middleware) is what you need.

In `middleware/auth.js`

```
// write any custom validation functions

export default function (context) {
  context.userAgent = process.server
    ? context.req.headers['user-agent']
    : navigator.userAgent
}
```

then in `nuxt.config.js`

```
// this will register the middleware functions above for every route

export default {
  router: {
    middleware: 'auth'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to your directory `middleware/` and create an `auth.js`

The first argument is your context. Context contains alot of things like your store, app, route, redirect, and it also contains `req`

You can check out what context has in it: https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/

```
export default function ({ req, res, redirect }) {
  let authenticated = false;
  if(!authenticated) {
     redirect("/login")
  }
}
```

You can go now to on of your page, and add this to your `export default {}`

```
middleware: ["auth"]
```

Now if you try to access the page you should be redirected to login